# component is not getting props

Tags: reactjs, components

i have two component

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class CourseSales extends Component {
  render(){
    var courses = this.props.items.map((item,i) => {
      return <Course name={item.name} price={item.price} key={i} />
    });
    return(
      <div>
          Purchase your course Here
          {courses}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Course extends Component {
  render(){
    console.log(this.porps);
    return(
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CourseSales;
```

i am not able to use name,price props in my Course Component console showing undefined
my Course component console.log showing undefined 
and my main app component code is

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import CourseSales from './CourseSales';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    var courses = [
      {'name':'design','price':2000},
      {'name':'backend','price':8000},
      {'name':'marketing','price':4000},
      {'name':'graphic design','price':10000},
    ]
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to Course Purchase App</h1>
        </header>
        <CourseSales items={courses} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

App component is working properly and if i just write any string in Course component it's showing it 4 times

Comment: then why its showing undefined in Course component

Comment: It's a typo: porps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are mapping everything fine in the CourseSales component.

Not sure if this typo is also in your code, but in your Course component it shows props misspelled:

```
console.log(this.porps);
```

Does it run if this is corrected?